# Is it possible unique user login in cake php

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i want to know the code for at a time single user login on any browser or computer of a 
user.

Can u help me.

Thanxs,

Comment: It's clear that English is not your first language. Please try to describe your goal in several simple sentences instead of one complicated sentence. It's incomprehensible what your question is.

Comment: I get SSO (Single Sign On) from this. But there has to be a certain token for that. ANY Browser and ANY Computer won't work unless it's within the same network which provides same credentials via all computers (Active Directory, LDAP etc). But enough guessing, please explain more of your wishes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

We are here to help with questions @Msofts, not to code for you. Please read

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/how-to-implament-one-time-password-for-forgot-my-password-and-account-activation-processes

and

http://spacebug.com/projects/cakeotp-one_time_password_reference_implementation_for_cakephp/

It should help with creating one time passwords. If what you need is single user access just follow the blog tutorial in the cake manual and give the password to only 1 user. furthermore, do not create a register page and that should do it.

Comment: The first thought should be "RTFM" +1

Comment: You know Leo that is one of the things that make Cake different; the fact that you have to forget what you know and stick to the actually learning the manual. It saves you so much misery. Other PHP Frameworks are more flexible but very disorganized and lack many features. I dare say anyone can code PHP but to be a true CakePHP programmer you need to actually be a programmer and have read the manual.